# What is the difference between Pytesseract and Tesserocr?

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I'm using Python 3.6 in Windows 10 and have Pytesseract already installed but I found in a [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54728733/moroccan-license-plate-recognition-lpr-using-opencv-and-tesseract) Tesserocr which by the way I can't install. What is the difference?

Comment: In addition to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56387215/11630056) in Tesserocr there is no support for Python 3.8 (April 2020).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pytesseract` is only a binding for `tesseract-ocr` for Python. So, if you want to use `tesseract-ocr` in python code without using `subprocess` or `os` module for running command line `tesseract-ocr` commands, then you use `pytesseract`. But, in order to use it, you have to have a `tesseract-ocr` installed.

You can think of it this way. You need a `tesseract-ocr` installed because it's the program that actually runs and does the OCR. But, if you want to run it from python code as a function, you install `pytesseract` package that enables you to do that. So when you run `pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('test-european.jpg'), lang='fra')`, it calls the `tesseract-ocr` with the provided arguments. The results are the same as running `tesseract test-european.jpg -l fra`. So, you get the ability to call that from the code, but in the end, it still has to run the `tesseract-ocr` to do the actual OCR.

Comment: Thanks a lot, now I understand... Do you have any idea on how to install tesserocr? If you have it installed what are the steps you followed and what version of Visual Studio you are using. Thank you again!

Comment: I have already installed tesseract for Windows, I need to install [tesserocr](https://pypi.org/project/tesserocr/) for python but it fails...

Comment: Then download desired version from [here](https://github.com/simonflueckiger/tesserocr-windows_build/releases) and the just run `pip install <downloaded-package>.whl`

Comment: This does not answer what is tesserocr, which is different from tesseract-ocr, as explained in https://stackoverflow.com/a/56387215/4974791

Answer (score 31):

From my experience Tesserocr is much faster than Pytesseract.

Tesserocr is a python wrapper around the Tesseract C++ API. Whereas `pytesseract` is a wrapper around the `tesseract-ocr` CLI.

With Tesserocr you can pre-load the model at the beginning or your program (which is called memoization), and run the model separately (for example in loops to process videos).

With `pytesseract`, each time you call `image_to_string` function, it loads the model and process the image, which makes it slower for repeated calls.

To install `tesserocr` I just typed in the terminal `pip install tesserocr`.

To use tesserocr

```
import tesserocr
from PIL import Image
api = tesserocr.PyTessBaseAPI()
pil_image = Image.open('sample.jpg')
api.SetImage(pil_image)
text = api.GetUTF8Text()
```

To install pytesseract : `pip install pytesseract`.

To run it :

```
import pytesseract
import cv2
image = cv2.imread('sample.jpg')
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(image)
```

Comment: For pytesseract no PIL needed?

Comment: `cv2 has no imread member`, but I get info when hovering over imread() in VSCode. Maybe cv2 is not installed, but I `pip`ed it and python -c 'import cv2' shows no error, just nothing.

Comment: another speed impact is that pytesseract (as of the time writing this comment) always writes images to disk instead of directly piping to tesseract, see https://github.com/madmaze/pytesseract/issues/172

Answer (score 4):

[Pytesseract](https://pypi.org/project/pytesseract/) is a python "wrapper" for the tesseract binary. It offers only the following functions, along with specifying flags ([man page](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/blob/master/doc/tesseract.1.asc#scripts)):

- `get_tesseract_version` Returns the Tesseract version installed in the system.
- `image_to_string` Returns the result of a Tesseract OCR run on the image to string
- `image_to_boxes` Returns result containing recognized characters and their box boundaries
- `image_to_data` Returns result containing box boundaries, confidences, and other information. Requires Tesseract 3.05+. For more information, please check the Tesseract TSV documentation
- `image_to_osd` Returns result containing information about orientation and script detection.

See the [project description](https://github.com/madmaze/pytesseract) for more information.

On the other hand, [tesserocr](https://github.com/sirfz/tesserocr) interfaces directly with Tesseract's C++ API ([APIExample](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/APIExample)) which is much more flexible/complex and offers advanced features.